# Не работает музыка и звуки в билде android игры Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

В редакторе unity музыка запускается и нормально работает.
Скрипт, который запускает музыку:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Music List", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Audio/Music/List")]
public class MusicList : ScriptableObject
{
    public AudioClip[] Clips;
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MusicList _list;
    private AudioSource _source;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _source.mute = !Settings.Music.IsChecked;
        Settings.Music.OnChanged += HandleChange;
    }

    private void HandleChange()
    {
        _source.mute = !Settings.Music.IsChecked;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Play();
    }

    private void Play()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ListLoopPlaying());
    }

    private IEnumerator ListLoopPlaying()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var clip in _list.Clips)
            {
                _source.clip = clip;
                _source.Play();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сам трек:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске игры в редакторе все работает как надо. Но после билда игры под андроид, и его запуска на телефоне музыка не воспроизводится.

Comment: попробуйте в другом формате, может что-то с кодеками не так, например в mp3

Comment: Так вся музыка и так в mp3.

Comment: у вас в настройках Vorbis

Comment: попробуйте еще сделать как в примере https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioClip.html